# Spark Listener to an SQL Query

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to develop a simple Spark application that will listen to a specific sql query in Spark such as the following:

```
hc.sql("load data 'location' inpath in table table_a")
```

What listener can I use that will listen to a specific sql query executed in Spark?

I learned of SQL Listener in a gitbooks website but it seems to me that it's available only in version 2.2+ but correct me if I'm wrong. The current version of my spark is 1.6.0 and I want to use that version respectively.

Any answers are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Data should be present in local location before you run this SQL. It's out of the box hive feature to load data in table from local location and you don't need to configure any listener explicitly.

Comment: Yes, but I'm just giving a simple example. What if for example I want to update a specific value for a global variable in the program let's say the count of a record everytime you perform a specific sql query? I just want to use a listener just for the sake of it.

Comment: Based on my experience there are no such listeners, what you would try using spark streaming to load data to hive table and if new file is arrived update variables. Other solution can be keep checking the table count if count is increased then update variables.